# OS X Server NFS home directory mount options

Tags: mac-osx, ldap, nfs, mac-osx-server, opendirectory

we are running a couple of OS X clients in an open directory OS X server environment with home directories provide via NFS.

The `auto_home` script allows to mount the home folder of the
user without changing the client, the directory util has two fields to setup the correct NFS mount:

```
NFSHomeDirectory: /home/testuser
HomeDirectory: <home_dir><url>nfs://SERVERNAME/Volumes/RAID/Users/testuser</url><path></path></home_dir>
```

On the clients the home directory is mounted and used correctly,

```
nfsstat -m
```

shows:

```
...
 NFS parameters: vers=3,tcp,port=2049,nomntudp,hard,nointr,noresvport,negnamecache,callumnt,locks,quota,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,readahead=16,dsize=32768,nordirplus,nodumbtimr,timeo=10,maxgroups=16,acregmin=5,acregmax=60,acdirmin=5,acdirmax=60,nomutejukebox,nonfc,sec=sys
...
```

which seems to use the OS X default NFS mount parameters.

Is there any way to configure those?

I'd like to change them to handle locks locally only and some other finetuning, but I don't find the correct way to configure the mount parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to configure the default mount options that `automountd` applies using the `AUTOMOUNTD_MNTOPTS` option in `/etc/autofs.conf`.

Alternatively, for just the home directory mounts, you can add options to the `auto_home` map in `/etc/auto_master`.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the options in the Directory Utility

Command + Spacebar > Type and open 'Directory Utility' > Directory Editor > Viewing > Mounts > NFS mount > VFSOpts > Unlock the locker > Modify the options then save